# SDL 2.0 - Blank Screen

Tags: c++, 2d, rendering, sprite, sdl-2

I've spent some time working with SDL 1.2 and made an ok system. I'm trying to convert it to 2.0 but I'm stuck getting it working mostly in regards to rendering textures. My screen is forever black and from what I can tell there are no errors but textures aren't rendering to my screen. Can someone point out what the problem is? The images do get recognised but just doesn't render.

Here is the relevant source code below:

```
m_window = SDL_CreateWindow
    (NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    w, h, 0);
m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, 0);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);

bool Image::Load(const std::string& filename)
{
    m_surface = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
    assert(m_surface);
    m_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(
       m_renderer, m_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(m_surface);
    return(m_texture != 0);
}

void Image::Draw(const Vec2f& pos)
{
    SDL_Rect dest;
    dest.h = 0;
    dest.w = 0;
    dest.x = (int)pos.GetX();
    dest.y = (int)pos.GetY();
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, &dest);
}
```

Comment: Are you applying your textures to left-hand or right-hand surfaces? Maybe you don't see anything just because the system only renders the "forward-facing polygons". If you rotate your polygons (or are unsure which way they are facing) - just make "duplicates" of each one of them. That kind of optimization (rather simplification) is widely used to ensure the texture is rendered regardless of the polygon's orientation. You might want to re-visit this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219684(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You are drawing your textures with a height and width of 0

```
void Image::Draw(const Vec2f& pos)
{
    SDL_Rect dest;
    dest.h = 0;    <------ Needs a valid size
    dest.w = 0;    <------ Needs a valid size
    dest.x = (int)pos.GetX();
    dest.y = (int)pos.GetY();
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, &dest);
}
```

You need to provide a valid size for the texture to draw at whether that be something you decide or whether it be the actual size of the texture which you store somewhere when it is loaded.

To test, just give it arbitrary values such as 100 for both width and height or just pass `NULL` instead of `&dest` (passing NULL will draw the texture full window size)